# Using docker-compose with the Bazel rules_docker?

Tags: docker-compose, bazel

How do I use docker-compose (or a similar tool) with Bazel's rules-docker?

I know I could generate images, container-push them, and then reference the version in a docker-compose.yaml, but I would like a more developer friendly way of working with docker files in a way I don't need to push images to test changes.

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing that if you don't want to push the image that you want to mess with compose locally?

For that you can `bazel run //path/to:image` to load it into your local Docker daemon, and reference the temporary name `bazel/path/to:image` in your compose file.

If you can elaborate a bit on exactly what you'd like to do, I'd be happy to try and help.

Comment: That is basically it. I can to test changes to a docker image without having to push the images every change.